# Multiplication Datetime * Double

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

Hello everyone my problem is very simple. Using entity framework code first

I want to multiply two properties in different tables. The problem is that before I used an int type and now I have to use the time. How can I do?

As I tried to nettere a thing in the property Time

```
public class Employe
{
    public Timespan Time { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public double Cost { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public double Total { get { return Cost * Employe.Time.TotalMinutes } }
}
```

What data type should I use to do this?

I have to multiply the cost over time because then I have to return a query with the total hours worked. The time represents the hours the employee

Comment: You multiply Cost by time? Erm, what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: The time represents the hours and minutes. I thought about using the String.Format for time

String.Format ("{0: h, mm"})

Comment: @MirkoPastorelli How can you multiply this by a Cost though? Perhaps show an example in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `Time` property is supposed to store how long an Employee has worked for, maybe you need the [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) type instead of `DateTime`. Then you could do something like

```
Cost * Time.TotalHours
```

Comment: can i multiply timespan type with double type?

Comment: @MirkoPastorelli: You don't multiply by the TimeSpan, but by one of its properties, like `TotalHours` as I've shown above. `TotalHours` is a double. Follow the link on `TimeSpan` above to see the MSDN documentation.

Comment: So the  Time data in Timespan... is right? and where should I declare totaLHour? thanks

Comment: @MirkoPastorelli I'm a bit confused. You have a property on your "Employe" class called "Time". I assume this is supposed to record the amount of time an employee has spent doing something. Is this correct? I'm saying you could change the type of this property from DateTime to TimeSpan. If you know the DateTime the employee started and the DateTime the employee ended, you can subtract one from the other to get a TimeSpan object. Then look at the TotalHours property of this object.

Comment: What I would like to make is that the employee may enter data such as

0.30 ,

1 h ,

1.30 h , 

2 ,

2.30 etc.

after this, then I have to multiply by the cost

Comment: So, you could do something like: `employee.Time = new TimeSpan(0,30,0);` to set the time as 30 minutes, then do `Total = employee.Time.TotalHours * Cost;`